# How to resolve JavaScript error: "$ is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript which is throwing an error on my Wordpress site:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.xxxxx.xxx/v1/identify',
success: function(data){
    //show data in your browser console
    console.log(data);

    //example on how to replace an element in your page
    if(data.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        $('.injected-header-text').html('Hi ' + data.name);
    }
}
});
```

```

after looking through a few threads I have changed the $.ajax into jQuery.ajax and that makes the requested results visible in Chrome console but not visible in my browser.

The error: JavaScript error: "$ is not a function"

This is what i have so far:

```
         <script>
jQuery.ajax({url: 'https://api.xxxx.xxx/v1/identify',
    success: function(data){
   //show data in your browser console
    console.log(data);

    //example on how to replace an element in your page
    if(data.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        $('.injected-header-text').html('Welkom ' + data.name);
    }
    }
    });
    </script>
    <div class=injected-header-text > </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript/jQuery cdn on top

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`